# Combining two strings to become a variable in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, variables

I was wondering if you could combine a variable and a string and assign it a variable in the same line.

> `choice + "xpos" -= 1`

Please Help

Comment: @funnyman: You are really funny man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want to create variables dynamically. You can... there are good ways to do this, and there are bad.

#### Good Way

Use a dictionary. For your case, preferably a `defaultdict`:

```
In [212]: from collections import defaultdict

In [213]: var_dict = defaultdict(int)

In [215]: choice = 'temp_'

In [216]: var_dict[choice + 'xpos'] -= 1

In [217]: var_dict
Out[217]: defaultdict(int, {'temp_xpos': -1})
```

#### Bad Way

You can also use `eval`, but I'm not going to show you how, because you shouldn't use it.